# Mixed model for pre-post study with small samples

Tags: mixed-model, normality-assumption

I have a simple pre-post study with 9 controls and 8 patients. The outcome variable is a length and I want to measure the effect of time and treatment. The intervals between the two observations for each subject is not the same, so I think to insert into a possible model the variable time, considered as continuous. I also have the necessity to measure possible effects of age. So, I thought that a mixed model with random intercept was a good answer to my question.

My model is (in R code):

```
model<-lme(length~time*treat+age,random=1|id)
```

It works quite well but analyzing residual violations of normality and homoscedasticity assumptions come out (maybe due to small sample size). Does it really matter or am I too rigorous?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any other suggestion on a possible substitute model or method is welcome!